# Too many tags for Windows installation?

Tags: discussion, tags

- [windows-installer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-installer) x119
- [windows-installation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-installation) x80

At least one needs to go. I would remove both and replace with applicable [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows), [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7), [windows-8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8), ... and optional [installation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/installation).

Comment: I actually like having a separate tag for the process of installing Windows. `[installation]` by itself is just too vague and actually quite the meta tag. (But ~2k questions, let's leave that alone)

Comment: I would have thought "windows installer" would refer to [the Microsoft product of the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) which produces installation wizards (or the use of those installers)

Comment: To clarify: I think Windows-installer is a valid tag, which should refer to Windows Installer issues (like programs that have been removed but still appear in the Programs and Features list) but should *not* refer to installing windows itself.

Comment: @BenBrocka: Interesting, didn't even think about that one

Answer (score 1):

I think windows-installer is a valid tag. However it is now sometimes being used for the OS installation process and not the [Windows Installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer). Could need some retag/cleanup and probably a more explaining tag-wiki.